# Filter Object based on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I’ve got an object having this form:

```
const obj = {
    abc: "Moon",
    def: "Earth",
    asd: "Sun",
    dmg: "Venus",
    xyz: "Mars",
    tuv: "Jupiter"
};
```

And an array with this form:

```
const arr = ["abc", "def", "tuv"];
```

I want to filter `obj` based on the values given in `arr`. That means, is there a way, probably using the filter method, to turn `obj` into this:

```
const newObj = {
    abc: "Moon",
    def: "Earth",
    tuv: "Jupiter"
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You could map new objects with wanted properties and assign all to a single object.

```js
const
    object = { abc: "Moon", def: "Earth", asd: "Sun", dmg: "Venus", xyz: "Mars", tuv: "Jupiter" },
    array = ["abc", "def", "tuv"],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any advantage over @mohammad-usman ’s approach?

Comment: it is just a different approach by generating single objects, instead of using a single object/accumulator of `reduce`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the resultant object:

```js
const arr = ["abc", "def", "tuv"];
const obj = {
    abc: "Moon",
    def: "Earth",
    asd: "Sun",
    dmg: "Venus",
    xyz: "Mars",
    tuv: "Jupiter"
};

const result = arr.reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = obj[c], r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfection! Could you briefly describe what the syntax does within the reduce()?

Comment: @Kalaschnik I've added a reference to the docs. It describes in detail how reduce works.